# async javascript function with multiple promises inside to return one final result

Tags: javascript, async-await

I currently have an async function that is similar to below. It returns an object which contains the results of several api calls(using axios - so each call returns a promise).

the problem i have is that the 3 api calls could be called at same time, but currently i am awaiting each one.

How would i be able to fire them all off at same time but still make sure the function only returns when all have finished. Do i need to put in a promise.all?

```
export async function GetItems(){
  let items ={
     items1:[],
     items2:[],
     items3:[]
  }

  await service.getItems1().then(r=>{
     items.items1 = r.data
  }

  await service.getItems2().then(r=>{
     items.items2 = r.data
  }

  await service.getItems3().then(r=>{
     items.items3 = r.data
  }

  return items;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: thanks for marking this as a duplicate, i can see from the answer in that question that i do indeed need to use `promise.all`

Comment: the referenced "duplicate" question is not directly applicable, IMHO.

Comment: you do need to use `Promise.all`, but you *don't* then use `await` to call the three other functions, you do `let p1 = service.getItems1( ... )`, etc, and then `return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])`.

Comment: @Alnitak how would i return my Items object?  what would i do if i had an if statement around that last promise would that change things?

Comment: `return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(() => items)`

Comment: or do `await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);    return items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an individual Promise for each action, without using `await`, (thereby allowing them to run concurrently) and then use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to complete:

```
export async function GetItems(){
  let items ={
     items1:[],
     items2:[],
     items3:[]
  }

  let p1 = service.getItems1().then(r=>{
     items.items1 = r.data
  }

  let p2 = service.getItems2().then(r=>{
     items.items2 = r.data
  }

  let p3 = service.getItems3().then(r=>{
     items.items3 = r.data
  }

  await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);

  return items;
}
```